# Calculate all roots of polynomial

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, roots

So I have a multivariate polynomial which is a [Bézier curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve). The curve can have any amount of points and is in 3D space.

Definition: https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/4aead49f2dc6a80c8f4018274355e8f48c38573a
I have the first and second derivative.

I need to find **all** roots of the first derivative, so when [image: Root]

Popular algorithms like Newton's method only find one root. Running the algorithm multiple times with different initial guesses is not reliable.

Other popular algorithms for finding all roots of polynomials like the Aberth method or Durand-Kerner method can only be used with univariate polynomials. The Wikipedia article says that [Bézier curves can be expressed in a polynomial form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Polynomial_form), but I don't know if that would work with the algorithms.

I've looked at [Real-root isolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-root_isolation), but I think it is for univariate polynomials as well.

Can anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your Bézier curve can have arbitrary degree, say $n$. Your statement saying “any number of points” somewhat implies this, but is a little ambiguous.

Also, I assume you’re still trying to find a tight box around the Bézier curve, as in your other recent question.

So, suppose you have already determined the orientation of the box, and $V$ is one of its axis vectors. We want to find the min/max extents of the curve in the $V$ direction (and then we’ll do the same calculation for the other two axis vectors). In other words, if $B(t)$ is the equation of the curve, we want to find the min and max values of the dot product $V \cdot B(t)$ for $t \in [0,1]$.

The min and max could occur at an end-point of the curve, which is the easy case. Alternatively, they could occur at some point that is a zero of the function $f(t)=V \cdot B’(t)$. The function $f(t)$ is a univariate polynomial of degree $n-1$, so you can use your favorite numerical methods to find its zeros.

Some numerical methods will require you to express $f$ in “power” form, i.e. in the form $a_0 + a_1t + \cdots + a_{n-1}t^{n-1}$. You can calculate the coefficients $a_i$ using the standard Bézier-to-power conversion, which is explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Polynomial_form).

Comment: Okay I will just use the polynomial form of the Bézier curve, thanks. The implementations of the Aberth method and Durand-Kerner method all use complex numbers in the calculation. Would it be possible to only use real numbers or do I have to use complex numbers as well?
Example: https://github.com/osveliz/numerical-veliz/blob/master/src/systems/DurandKernerAberthEhrlich.go

Comment: I have no experience with those methods, but it looks like complex numbers are required. Most programming environments have decent support for complex numbers, so that doesn’t seem like a big problem, to me.